# ¿Cómo ordenar lista luego de hacer un set python?

Tags: python, lista

Tengo una lista con nombres, en la misma hay nombres repetidos, quiero que la lista quede en el mismo orden en el que aparecen los items.

```
#nombres:
nombres = ["Rodrigo","Rodrigo","Alberto","Juan","Juan","Mario","Juan","Mario","Mario","Rodrigo","Juan"]
#elimina los items repetidos pero desornados,
set(nombres)
{'Alberto', 'Juan', 'Mario', 'Rodrigo'}

list(set(nombres))
>>['Rodrigo', 'Alberto', 'Mario', 'Juan']
```

**Mi objetivo es que imprima lo siguiente:**

```
>>['Rodrigo', 'Alberto', 'Juan', 'Mario']
```

No me sirve `.sort()` ya que solo ordena alfabéticamente, y necesito mantenga el mismo orden en el que se guardaron los items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

puedes hacerlo con el metodo `dict.fromkeys`  devuelve un nuevo diccionario con la secuencia de elementos dada como las claves del diccionario `key` dict() y como no pueden existir 2 `keys` iguales elimina los duplicados en el orden de entrada, luego lo volvemos a pasar a `list()` y listo!

**ejemplo:**

```
nombres = ["Rodrigo","Rodrigo","Alberto","Juan","Juan","Mario","Juan","Mario","Mario","Rodrigo","Juan"]
orden = list(dict.fromkeys(nombres))
print(orden)
['Rodrigo', 'Alberto', 'Juan', 'Mario']
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar un `for` añadiendo los valores a una nueva lista si no se encuentra en ella, y asi manteniendo el orden.

**Codigo for**

```
nueva_lista = []
for i in nombres:
    if i not in nueva_lista:
        nueva_lista.append(i)
```

O podrías usar el metodo `setdefault`, devuelve un valor de no encontrarse una `key` en un diccionario, tiene como primer parámetro la `key` y de segundo el `valor`.

**Codigo setdefault**

```
diccionario = dict()
nueva_lista = [diccionario.setdefault(n,n) for n in nombres if n not in diccionario]
```

Como ves añade el nombre como `valor` de una `clave` con su mismo nombre, pero solo si la clave no esta en el diccionario, para eso el `if`